# Unable to re-calculate total sum of dynamically added input after delete input using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have a form, i am able to  calculate total of all dynamically added inputs, but i am to re-calculate  after the delete row, Here is my code.

I have followed the code,

http://jsfiddle.net/Uwbe6/2/

```js
calcSum();

function calcSum() {
  var myForm = $('#myForm');
  myForm.delegate('.items', 'change', function() {
    var sum = 0;
    var itemsValue = myForm.find('.items');
    itemsValue.each(function() {
      var value = Number($(this).val());
      if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
      // sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    // return sum;
    $('.total-amt').html(sum);
    // console.log(sum);
  });
}

$('body').on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  calcSum();
});

$(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('#add_more').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input.items').last().attr('name', 'item[' + i + ']');
    $('#cart_items').append($('#tmp_cart').html());
    i++;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm">
  Total Items<input type="text" value="100" name="total_amt" id="total_amt">
  <div id="cart_items">
    Items<input type="text" name="item[0]" class="items"><br/>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="add_more">Add More</button>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<p>Total Amt:<span class="total-amt"></span></p>
<div id="tmp_cart" style="display: none;">
  <div class="cart_items">
    <label>
      Items
      <input type="text" name="item[]" class="items">
    </label>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete"><br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: `.delegate()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()`

Comment: Hi @Barmar, if i use on() function instead delegate() it was not working

Comment: You must have been using it wrong. I use it in my answer and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calcSum()` should just calculate the sum, not bind a handler. Then you can call it from different handlers.

```js
calcSum();

function calcSum() {
  var myForm = $('#myForm');
  var sum = 0;
  var itemsValue = myForm.find('.items');
  itemsValue.each(function() {
    var value = Number($(this).val());
    if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
    // sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  // return sum;
  $('.total-amt').html(sum);
  // console.log(sum);
}

$("#myForm").on("change", ".items", calcSum);

$('body').on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  calcSum();
});

$(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('#add_more').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input.items').last().attr('name', 'item[' + i + ']');
    $('#cart_items').append($('#tmp_cart').html());
    i++;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm">
  Total Items<input type="text" value="100" name="total_amt" id="total_amt">
  <div id="cart_items">
    Items<input type="text" name="item[0]" class="items"><br/>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="add_more">Add More</button>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<p>Total Amt:<span class="total-amt"></span></p>
<div id="tmp_cart" style="display: none;">
  <div class="cart_items">
    <label>
      Items
      <input type="text" name="item[]" class="items">
    </label>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete"><br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .on() instead of `.delegate()` since it's deprecated. Also, you could simply keep the event binding separate from calcSum function.

```js
var myForm = $('#myForm');
calcSum();

function calcSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    var itemsValue = myForm.find('.items');
    itemsValue.each(function() {
      var value = Number($(this).val());
      if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
      // sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    // return sum;
    $('.total-amt').html(sum);
    // console.log(sum);
}

myForm.on('change', calcSum);

$('body').on("click", '.delete', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  calcSum();
});

$(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('#add_more').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input.items').last().attr('name', 'item[' + i + ']');
    $('#cart_items').append($('#tmp_cart').html());
    i++;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="myForm">
  Total Items<input type="text" value="100" name="total_amt" id="total_amt">
  <div id="cart_items">
    Items<input type="text" name="item[0]" class="items"><br/>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="add_more">Add More</button>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<p>Total Amt:<span class="total-amt"></span></p>
<div id="tmp_cart" style="display: none;">
  <div class="cart_items">
    <label>
      Items
      <input type="text" name="item[]" class="items">
    </label>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete"><br/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks identical to my answer.

Comment: definitely. You were quick. I was just typing the answer and saw you already posted.

Comment: I posted it 15 minutes before you.